# Unable to add Items in SharePoint list using app model

Tags: sharepoint-online, apps-development

I need to add the list item using app model. I had written the
   below code to add list item. I am getting prompted on all the steps.

But I find no luck to in getting added to SharePoint list. Can any one on let me know what's wrong in my below code that's not reflecting?

```
'use strict';



var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var user = context.get_web().get_currentUser();
var mylist = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Customer");

// This code runs when the DOM is ready and creates a context object which is needed to use the SharePoint object model
$(document).ready(function () {
    getUserName();
});

// This function prepares, loads, and then executes a SharePoint query to get the current users information
function getUserName() {
    alert("Hi");
    context.load(user);
    context.executeQueryAsync(onGetUserNameSuccess, onGetUserNameFail);
}

function alertit()
{

    alert("We are in function to add items");
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    alert("Got URL");
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Customer');
    alert("Got The List");
    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    alert("Item Created Information");
    this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);//SecondQText
    alert("Item Object Created");
    oListItem.set_item('FirstName', "q1value");
    alert("Updated the Column Value to List Item");
    oListItem.update();
    alert("Item Added");
    clientContext.load(oListItem);
    context.executeQueryAsync(onGetUserNameSuccess, onGetUserNameFail);
}

// This function is executed if the above call is successful
// It replaces the contents of the 'message' element with the user name
function onGetUserNameSuccess() {
    alert("Item Added Successfully");
    $('#message').text('Item ' + user.get_title());
}

// This function is executed if the above call fails
function onGetUserNameFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Failed to get user name. Error:' + args.get_message());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a function alertit() which you have never invoked in your code.

Either call it in the success callback of  getUserName() or call it directly on document ready function as i see no need to get the user details in this case.